# How to set remember me cookie when logging user inside Controller in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, session, session-cookies, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.4

I have made my own custom FB login function because I need a certain flow that I couldn't achieve with HWIOAuthBundle. Everything works great, except one thing... I don't know how to set remember me functionality when I log in a user through my controller.

This is the LOGIN code I've got so far:

```
public function loginAction() {
        // Facebook login code here
        ...

        // User already connected with FB acc. Just log in.
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "main", $user->getRoles());
        $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);

        //now dispatch the login event
        $request = $this->get("request");
        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

        // Redirect user to hime page
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('/home'));
}
```

Thank you for any help or advice in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this remember token not the normal one it should be fixed :

```
$key = $this->container->getParameter('secret');
$token = new RememberMeToken($user, 'main', $key); //main is your firewall use name you gave to it.
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Comment: This throws me a 500 error: $providerKey must not be empty. How do I set this value?

Comment: `$providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');`

Comment: I tried switching between usernamepasswordtoken and remembermetoken but it made no difference to me, a remember me cookie is still not set, and both login the user just the same.

Comment: The [class constructor](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/RememberMeToken.html#method___construct) has only 3 parameters: `public __construct(UserInterface $user, string $providerKey, string $key)`. There is 4 parameters in your answer.

Comment: true confused it with the UsernamePasswordToken, i edit it